# Tag for (videos)?

Tags: discussion, tagging

I'd say that we have quite a lot of questions asking for videos of lectures about some particular topic or area. Just try to search for [video](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=video) on the main.

I think that such question could be tagged [online-resources](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-resources).<sup>1</sup> Would it be useful to introduce a more specialized [videos](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/videos) tag?

There are also questions about documentaries and movies about mathematics. (Try searching for [documentary](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=documentary) or [movie](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=movie) to see a few examples. If we create this tag, such questions could also belong there.

<sup>1</sup> Admittedly, videos need not be necessarily watched online. But the same is true about most of other online resources; they can be downloaded and accessed offline. But main reason for choosing this tag is that it is the closest tag to [videos](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/videos) that I know of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest to stick with [online-resources](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-resources). Otherwise we could be splitting hairs more and more: videos of lectures are not nearly same thing as Vi Hart videos, nor do they serve the same purpose. And then there are screencast videos with voiceover, which are also somehow different.