# What about (lecture-notes) tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging

There are many questions asking for lecture notes on some topic. And about [a week ago](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740/2017/7/2) also the tag [lecture-notes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lecture-notes) has been created. The question is to which extent this tag can be useful and whether it should be kept or removed. (In any case, since the new tag can affect many question, I think it is good to discuss it on meta before taking any further actions.)

- Currently [there are 3 questions](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38679322#38679322) having that tag. In two cases the tag was added by the tag-creator. In the third case I do not think the tag fits: [Spoof lecture for beginning first year undergraduates](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2351505).
- As far as I can say, the questions of this type have been so far usually tagged [reference-request](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) or, more specifically, [reference-request+online-resources](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request+online-resources).
- The situation is somewhat similar to [discussion about separate tag for videos](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15169/tag-for-videos), where the conclusion was to use [online-resources](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-resources). However, the difference is that we have more often questions about lecture notes than questions about videos.
- Another similar tag is [book-recommendation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-recommendation). Creation of this tag has been discussed here: [Do we need a tag for Books?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10393)
- I can easily imagine question which ask both for books and lecture notes. Such question would be tagged [reference-request](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request), [book-recommendation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-recommendation), [lecture-notes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lecture-notes) and possibly also [online-resources](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/online-resources). Considering that a question can only have 5 tags, this would already take large part of available slots without saying anything about the mathematical classification of the topic.
- If the tag is kept, it should be added at least to some most prominent past questions asking for lecture notes - so that this new tag is actually useful for searching.
- And if the tag stays, it would be good to created also some tag-info containing the guidance of the usage of this tag.

Comment: I don't think that we really need a lecture notes tag.

Comment: I think if we have a tag for books it isn't unreasonable to have a tag for lecture notes. But I don't think the two tags should generally be used together. If someone is looking for a reference that could be a book or lecture notes, then just use the [tag:reference-request] tag. I think the [tag:book-recommendation] tag should only be used if the references are *required* to be books.

Comment: If we are going to get rid of the tag, do we want it merged into (reference-request) or into (online-resources)?

Comment: @T.Gunn I guess if the number of the question stays low before decision in some direction is taken, then manual retagging is feasible (rather then merging two tags by a moderator). Personally, I think that question suitable for (lecture-notes) tag should have both (reference-request) and (online-resources) tag, if this tags is going to be removed.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say no.

Because the `lecture-notes` would fall inside the scope of [`reference-request`](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) tag:

> This tag is for questions seeking external references (books, articles, etc.) about a particular subject. Please do not use this as the only tag for a question.

And most of them would be `online-resources`.

So `lecture-notes` would be in both of these tags, as you said in your comment.

Comment: This tag contains 31 questions at the moment. So you propose to remove the tag, right? Either by manual removal or in some other way.

Comment: @MartinSleziak it's been like 6 years, and there's 31 questions at the moment. what do you mean by -in some other way-?

Comment: @MartinSleziak btw, this could be confusing, on one side there is 31 questions, but on the other side there's like [1k](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?page=1&tab=Relevance&pagesize=50&q=lecture%20notes%20%5breference-request%5d&searchOn=3)?

Comment: By "some other way" I mean that moderators can merge one tag into another - and in that way they can remove a tag without bumping (if there is a suitable replacement for all questions). And there is also a burnination of a tag - this can only be done by a CM, (But typically, this is used only when the tag has many questions.) In any case, such activities are likely to be resumed only after the strike ends.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Ok, thanks. Considering mainly [tag:online-resources], and the point number 5 on your post, then is a no for the tag `lecture-notes`.

Comment: @MartinSleziak https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64015698#64015698 Thanks Martin.